# How can I delete a row using the reduce method from my redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this function in my reducer where I am returning my updated cart

```
function updateCartInfo(cartItem, list) {
    const { id } = cartItem;
    const newList = new Map([...list.entries()]);

    newList.set(id, cartItem);

    return newList;
}
```

Then this is the case I am using to assign this function, where cart is an array of my cart object.

```
case UPDATE_CART_INFO: {
            const { payload } = action;
            const { cart } = state;

            return {
                ...state,
                cart: updateCartInfo(payload, cart),
            };
        }
```

Now inside my component I am trying to write a function that will remove a row using the reduce() by its id. How can I proceed from here

```
handleRemove = () => {
        const { cart } = this.props;
        const row = cart.get(id);

        return cart.reduce((list, item) => {

        })
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this, after spreading your cart `Map`. If the id you're using is the same one on the cart items it's straightforward:

```
 handleRemove = () => {
    const { cart } = this.props;
    const filteredMap = [...cart].filter(([key, item])=> key !== id)
    return new Map(filteredMap)
};
```

Comment: I just noticed something, cart is a map. I believe the high order functions are supposed to work on arrays, so the function does not work. How do I get my cart to be an array?

Comment: Thank you @Will Jenkins